# Swagger PHP & OA3 - Send simple formData

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, openapi

I use Laravel + Swagger + OpenAPI3 to create an API.

I want to simple use a classic login service, for now I have :

```
/**
 * Get a JWT via given credentials.
 *
 * @OA\Post(
 *     path="/login/login",
 *     tags={"Auth"},
 *     summary="Post login credentials",
 *     @OA\RequestBody(
 *          description= "Provide auth credentials",
 *          required=true,
 *          @OA\JsonContent(
 *              type="object",
 *              @OA\Property(property="email", type="string"),
 *              @OA\Property(property="password", type="string")
 *          )
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Response(
 *         response=200,
 *         description="get token",
 *      ),
 *    )
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function login()
{
    // .....
```

Which is ok, but how can I use formData here ? Looking at doc : https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/, I see they use form-url-encoded, but how can I translate it in PHP annotations ?

Comment: Have you tried `@OA\MediaType` + `@OA\Schema`, like done here -- https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/Examples/petstore-3.0/models/RequestBody.php#L14-L16?

Comment: I am still trying to find a good way, documentation is terrible and I would like to avoid schemas for a so simple form..